# Two external displays without Thunderbolt

Tags: hardware, display

I need to buy a new laptop (Mac) for work and the top priority for me is having at least two displays.

Unfortunately, due to budget limitations I cannot buy Apple Thunderbolt Displays. Now, and correct me if I’m wrong, the Apple Thunderbolt Display currently seems to be the only Thunderbolt display out there.

**Is it possible, using MBP or MacBook Air, to use two external displays that do *not* s use Thunderbolt?** … *Without* using additional hardware ([like the Matrox multiplexer used elsewhere](http://daggle.com/macbook-pro-multimonitor-4-monitors-at-once-1577) – this doesn’t work, and the DisplayLink USB to DVI adapter drivers don’t work yet on OS X Lion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using a DisplayLink USB to DVI adapter on Lion since the day Lion shipped, and I haven't had any trouble with it.  Actually, it's been better than with Snow Leopard because the new beta driver doesn't crash like the SL driver did.

Comment: This seems to be the only real viable solution and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

No - you need at least an USB to whatever input your third display (the second external display) accepts.

---

I suppose some would say you could use another computer and use some sort of virtual screen / VNC software to have the system make a virtual screen and send that data over the network to the other computer to push to the third display.

Comment: USB to display seems to be generally hacky, and DisplayLink says that their drivers don’t work on Lion yet, so this is unfortunately not an alternative.

Comment: My solution to this was to get an iMac.

Comment: The USB solution is certainly inferior to a real display hooked to any GPU even if it's year old, but if you truly need the real estate more than the $1k it is almost free in comparison to the second proper monitor.

Answer (score 4):

There are issues with specific older models of Mac (particularly those with nVidia graphics), but I've been using a DisplayLink adapter with Lion for several months without problem. My secondary display is even rotated 90 degrees.

Beta drivers are available [here](http://www.displaylink.com/support/mac_downloads.php) and known issues are described [here](http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=1059).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ScreenRecycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/). You'll need another computer, but even an old junker will work.

Comment: Hmm, to be honest this seems like a too clunky hack for my purpose (I have only limited control over the hardware setup) but perhaps other people can benefit from this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your definition of "additional hardware", the [ZOTAC Mini-DisplayPort to Dual HDMI Adaptor](http://www.engadget.com/2011/08/03/zotac-adapter-turns-your-displayport-into-two-hdmi-jacks/) might be a viable solution. It's more like a cable/adaptor than the Matrox box, and it has a price tag around $50. I have not seen this gadget in action first-hand, but a friend of mine has one, and he is very happy with it.

Google tells me that several stores carries the [ZT-MDP2HD](https://www.google.com/search?q=ZT-MDP2HD), including [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812500002).

Comment: I bought the adapter. Unfortunately, it now turns out that the adapter currently doesn’t work on OS X at all. In practice this means that I can either mirror my display (wow) or stretch it – but only up to measly resolutions which don’t do my 24" displays justice, and appear stretched.

Comment: … Which is supremely weird given the fact that (according to Wikipedia) Mini DisplayPorts appear in almost no other hardware.

Comment: More details: despite what Zotac’s page implies there don’t seem to be *any* drivers for this piece of hardware, and as such the system recognises this system as *one* screen with a maximum total resolution of 1920×1200 which is just patently ridiculous for two 24" screens (*each* of my displays has this resolution so I need twice that). This product simply doesn’t work as promised.